# Problems calculating absolute div

Tags: javascript

i have created vertical Menu with fixed width and absolute position ul

```
.categories ul.sub {
position: absolute;
right: -191px;
top: 0;
background: #fff;
width: 190px;}
```

but the problem is that i dont want to use fixed width and right. I want to calculate the width and the right of a ul depending of h2 class width inside ul with js. example : how is now: http://prntscr.com/rzcvx , how i need: http://prntscr.com/rzd3t

html example:

```
<div class="categories">
<ul class="maincats">
    <li>
        <a class="first"><img/><span>Category Name</span></a>
        <ul class="sub first">
            <li><h2>H2 Title</h2></li>
            <li>Title</li>
            <li>Title</li>
            <li>Title</li>
            <li>Title</li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul></div>
```

i have nothing tried yet, i only use this js

```
  $(".categories li a").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $(this).next('ul.sub').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $(this).next('ul.sub').hide();
        }


    );

  $(".categories ul.sub").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).prev().addClass("hover");
            $(this).show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).prev().removeClass("hover");
            $(this).hide();
        }


    );

  $(function () {
      var zIndexNumber = 10;
      // Put your target element(s) in the selector below!
      $(".categories ul.sub").each(function () {
          $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);

      });
  });
```

Please help me i have basic js skils :)

Comment: provide  http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
.categories ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%; /* Not sure if this works, can't test without your html */
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent spaces from wrapping when text's overflowing. */
}
```